# How to use GitLab in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: gitlab, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 comes with direct support of GitHub, but I am failing to find a possibility to use GitLab.

We have our own local GitLab server running and I was looking for a possibility to define the server I want to connect to, and turn my project into a GitLab repository from within Visual Studio.

It is possible to use the GitChange window if there is a local repository within the project beforehand, but in this case... than I can do everything in Git Bash.

The extension *GitLab Extension for Visual Studio* does not work for me at all, and was until now a waste of time and resources.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [GitLab Extension for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MysticBoy.GitLabExtensionforVisualStudio) for work on gitlab repositories.
this article can help

https://junaidshahid.com/gitlab-integration-with-visual-studio-2019/